# Convert WMI call to CIM call

Tags: powershell, wmi, cim

The code I am writing is suppose to kick off any patches currently available to a server using CIM.  And I have to use CIM due to the required DCOM protocol for my network.

I'm using ` for easier viewing

The following wmi code works:

```
$ComputerName = 'Foo'
[System.Management.ManagementObject[]] $CMMissingUpdates = @(`
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName `
                  -Query "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate WHERE ComplianceState = '0'" `
                  -Namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" `
                  -ErrorAction Stop)
$null = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName `
                       -Namespace "root\ccm\ClientSDK" `
                       -Class "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager" `
                       -List).InstallUpdates($CMMissingUpdates)
```

What I've made using CIM that doesn't work:

```
$null = (Invoke-CimMethod -CimSession $Computer.CimSession `
                          -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' `
                          -ClassName 'CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager' `
                          -MethodName 'InstallUpdates').InstallUpdates($CMMissingUpdates)
```

Not only am I interested in a solution to my `Invoke-CimMethod` but how it was solved.  I can't seem to determine how to view and implement the methods of classes in CIM.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a casting issue.  Link to solution:  https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8zvsd8/kick_off_a_sccm_clients_install_all_available/

The final solution:

```
$CMMissingUpdates = @( `
  Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate WHERE ComplianceState = '0'" `
                  -Namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK"
)
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace 'ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK' `
                 -ClassName 'CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager' `
                 -MethodName 'InstallUpdates' `
                 -Arguments @{ 
                    CCMUpdates = [cminstance[]]$CMMissingUpdates
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're using two incompatible commands to translate.

```
Invoke-CimMethod == Invoke-WmiMethod
```

`Get-WmiObject` is not the above, however.  Here's a way to accomplish what you're doing:

```
$ComputerName = 'Foo'
$cimArgs = @{
    'Namespace'    = 'Root\CCM\ClientSDK'
    'ClassName'    = 'CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager'
    'MethodName'   = 'InstallUpdates' # returns UInt32 object; 0 = success
    'Arguments'    = @{
        'CCMUpdates' = Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\CCM\ClientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdate -Filter 'ComplianceState = "0"'
    }
    'CimSession'   = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -SessionOption (New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom)
}
Invoke-CimMethod @cimArgs
```

The `Invoke-CimMethod` cmdlet takes a dictionary to pass arguments to the method.  I determined the keys/values based on [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155391.aspx).

This can alternatively be found by the following:

```
Get-CimClass -ClassName 'CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager' -Namespace 'Root\CCM\ClientSDK' |
     ForEach-Object -MemberName CimClassMethods
```

Comment: When I use your code I get the following error.

`Invoke-CimMethod : Could not infer CimType from the provided .NET object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod @cimArgs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-CimMethod], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.Management.Infrastru 
   cture.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand` @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: Also, all I am attempting to do is kick off the SCCM "Install All" patches that are currently listed as available on the SCCM Client.

Comment: @Keith According to the error message, it's a type issue.  The method expects `CCM_SoftwareUpdate`.  Your type-casting is unnecessary with `[ManagementObject]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigble1 When I test it without the type-casting, I get the same error.  I just want to be able to kick off the installation of any SCCM patches currently listed in the SCCM Client on the computer using CIM.  Perhaps `invoke-cimmethod` is not the correct approach.  Do you know an an alternative that would illicit the result I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use `Get-CimInstance` which is equivalent to `Get-WmiObject` (for the most part).  I'll update my answer using this method.